# Wordpress : Thumbnail posts show up for home page post, but not for all for category post

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, categories, posts

The home page shows thumbnail picture for posts... however posts listed on category does not show thumbnail for all posts..it shows for some post and does not show for some post.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `category.php` template if it includes the thumbnail function used at the home page.

Comment: there is no category.php available on my theme "socrates"